# Realizar POST añadiendo Header y Params

Tags: angular, http, cabeceras-http

Estoy intentando realizar un login mediante tokens en Angular. Para ello necesito enviar el usuario y contraseña mediante método POST incluyendo cabecera y parametro.

Estos son la cabecera y los parametros:

```
'Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
'scope','...lo que sea...'
'grant_type', 'password'
'Authorization','... lo que sea...'
```

Pero no se como inlcuir estos datos en el POST para que me devuelva el access_token y los demás campos.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
let cabecera = new HttpHeaders();
let parametros = new HttpParams();

cabecera.set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization','...');
parametros.set('grant_type', 'password');
parametros.set('scope','...');

let opciones = {
  headers: cabecera,
  params: parametros
}

this.http.post(this.url,opciones).subscribe(data =>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

Pero no se agregar de esta forma el usuario y la contraseña para que lo verifique. Y me devuelve errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de esta forma:

```
login(login){

    let parametros = new HttpParams();
    parametros = parametros.append('grant_type','----');
    parametros = parametros.append('scope','-- lo que sea--');
    parametros = parametros.append('username',login.username);
    parametros = parametros.append('password',login.password);

    const opciones = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':'---',
        'Authorization': '-- lo que sea --'
      }),
      params: parametros
    };

    return this.http.post(`${this.URL}/token`,login,opciones);
}
```

Tuve que añadir el usuario y password dentro de los parámetros también.

Answer (score 0):

Hola me parece que estas pasando mal los parametros al POST, te muestro un ejemplo de un POST:

```
    //Header json
    const headers: any = {
       "Authorization": "ACCESS TOKEN"
    };

    //Post options pass it to HttpHeaders Class 
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(headers),
    };

    //Url
    const url: string = "https://url.com/uri";

    //Do request
    return this.httpClient.post(url, obj, httpOptions)
```

El metodo `post`, acepta 3 argumentos, `URL` que es la dirección HTTP destino, `OBJ` que es el json a mandar como body del request, y el 3er parámetro es `OPTIONS`, que puedes utilizar para mandar los headers que precisas, así como esta en el ejemplo de arriba.(https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)

Comment: Por favor explica el código. Saludos.

Comment: Hola!, el `post` acepta 3 parámetros, URL, OBJ que es el json a mandar como body del request, y el 3er parámetro es OPTIONS, que puedes utilizar para mandar los headers que precisas. acá esta el link que lo explica cada parámetro https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: La explicación debe ir en la respuesta, por favor edita tu respuesta y coloca la explicación de tu código. Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa José, soy nuevo en esto, ahí edité la respuesta, espero que te pueda ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Tranquilo, no tienes por que pedir disculpas, solamente se hacen las observaciones en busca de mejorar las respuestas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa que es importante saber sobre Angular y su forma de tratar las peticiones es que los objetos `HttpHeaders` y `HttpParams` son **inmutables**. Cada vez que usas el método `set(...)`, tienes que guardar el objeto devuelto.

Un ejemplo de petición podría ser así:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    ...
  ) { }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<...> {
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append('Authorization', `Basic ${this.b64EncodeUnicode(username + ':' + password)}`)
      .append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    return this.http.post<string>(ENV.url.login, null, { headers: headers }).pipe(
      map((data: string) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (data) {
          return data;
        } else {
          // failed login
          return null;
        }

      }),
      catchError((error: any) =>
        observableThrowError(error || 'Server error'))
    );
  }

  b64EncodeUnicode(str: string): string {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, (match, p1) => {
      return String.fromCharCode(('0x' + p1) as any);
    }));
  }
}
```

Explicación:

Una forma habitual de de enviar el usuario y el password es la [autenticación básica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso_b%C3%A1sica#Lado_Cliente), que requiere pasar a Base64 la cadena `'Basic <usuario>:<password>'` en el header `"Authorization"`. La respuesta del servidor puede variar, desde mandar sólo el token o mandarlo con más información en un JSON u otro formato.
El problema es que pasar a base 64 caracteres especiales puede ser fuente de problemas, así que en el ejemplo dado se realizan ciertas transformaciones previas, por eso añadí el método `b64EncodeUnicode`.